# android color between two colors, based on percentage?

Tags: java, android, colors

I would like to calculate the color depending on a percentage value:

```
float percentage = x/total;
int color;
if (percentage >= 0.95) {
  color = Color.GREEN;
} else if (percentage <= 0.5) {
  color = Color.RED;
} else {
  // color = getColor(Color.Green, Color.RED, percentage);
}
```

How can I calculate that last thing? It would be OK if yellow appears at 50%.

I tried this:

```
private int getColor(int c0, int c1, float p) {
    int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
    int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
    int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
    int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);
    return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}
private int ave(int src, int dst, float p) {
    return src + java.lang.Math.round(p * (dst - src));
}
```

Well this works, but I would like the colors at around 50% being more lightend as I use them on a grey background.. how can I accomplish that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I tried to convert to YUV like it was suggested in the comments. But I still have the same problem that at 50% it's to dark.
Additional in this solution I have at <5% now white as color. If I do not calculate `float y = ave(...);`, but just take `float y = c0.y` it's a little better, but at <20% I have then cyan color ... I'm not so much into color-formats :-/
Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the calculation? The constants are taken from Wikipedia

```
public class ColorUtils {

    private static class Yuv {
        public float y;
        public float u;
        public float v;

        public Yuv(int c) {
            int r = Color.red(c);
            int g = Color.green(c);
            int b = Color.blue(c);
            this.y = 0.299f * r + 0.587f * g + 0.114f * b;
            this.u = (b - y) * 0.493f;
            this.v = (r - y) * 0.877f;
        }
    }

    public static int getColor(int color0, int color1, float p) {
        Yuv c0 = new Yuv(color0);
        Yuv c1 = new Yuv(color1);
        float y = ave(c0.y, c1.y, p);
        float u = ave(c0.u, c1.u, p);
        float v = ave(c0.v, c1.v, p);

        int b = (int) (y + u / 0.493f);
        int r = (int) (y + v / 0.877f);
        int g = (int) (1.7f * y - 0.509f * r - 0.194f * b);

        return Color.rgb(r, g, b);
    }

    private static float ave(float src, float dst, float p) {
        return src + Math.round(p * (dst - src));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered converting to YUV and comparing luminance values?

Comment: yes, I edited it to the question... it's the same problem there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after 2 hours of converting to yuv, hsv, etc pp... I give up. I now do it just like this:

```
public class ColorUtils {
    private static int FIRST_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    private static int SECOND_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static int THIRD_COLOR = Color.RED;

    public static int getColor(float p) {
        int c0;
        int c1;
        if (p <= 0.5f) {
            p *= 2;
            c0 = FIRST_COLOR;
            c1 = SECOND_COLOR;
        } else {
            p = (p - 0.5f) * 2;
            c0 = SECOND_COLOR;
            c1 = THIRD_COLOR;
        }
        int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
        int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
        int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
        int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);
        return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    private static int ave(int src, int dst, float p) {
        return src + java.lang.Math.round(p * (dst - src));
    }
}
```

By explicity using yellow as the middle color, the generated colors are brighter :-)

Anyway.. if someone has a good other solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 76):

You can try using ArgbEvaluator class from android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html :

```
new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(0.75, 0x00ff00, 0xff0000);
```

Note that there is a bug ( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36158 ) in alpha channel calculation so you should use values without alpha value.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Cast result to int: `int color = (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(0.75, 0x00ff00, 0xff0000);`

Comment: Note that this class requires API level 11+!

Comment: To use color resources for this, use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)` instead of just the `R.color.my_color` int

Comment: I wonder why they made ArgbEvaluator work with Objects instead of ints. So many casts and enveloping during animation are unnecessary overhead.

Comment: import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;

Comment: @auval that's how java works. `evaluate(float, X, X)` is a part of generic interface `TypeEvaluator`. Generic parameters have to be objects (unlike c++ templates, for example), so `Integer` has to be used here.

Comment: will this actually fade the colour or just jump between the 2 colours?

Answer (score 32):

My $0.02, I found this answer and coded up the proper solution. (Thanks to Alnitak for the HSV tip!)

For Copy+Paste:

```
  private float interpolate(float a, float b, float proportion) {
    return (a + ((b - a) * proportion));
  }

  /** Returns an interpoloated color, between <code>a</code> and <code>b</code> */
  private int interpolateColor(int a, int b, float proportion) {
    float[] hsva = new float[3];
    float[] hsvb = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(a, hsva);
    Color.colorToHSV(b, hsvb);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      hsvb[i] = interpolate(hsva[i], hsvb[i], proportion);
    }
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsvb);
  }
```

Comment: It should be noted that this won't handle an alpha channel. From `Color.colorToHSV` docs: "color - the argb color to convert. The alpha component is ignored."

Comment: I updated your answer to handle alpha here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38536770/1650674

Comment: almost, I get yellow when interpolate between blue and red but want pink.

Answer (score 24):

As an updated solution, you can use `ColorUtils#blendARGB` from the [Android support](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html#blendARGB(int,%20int,%20float)) or [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/ColorUtils#blendargb) APIs:

```
val startColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)
val endColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yellow)
ColorUtils.blendARGB(startColor, endColor, 0.75)
```

Comment: short and crisp works like a charm !

Answer (score 9):

Interpolation like this is best done in [HSL or HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLS_color_space) color spaces (and not YUV).

The reason the mid range colours look "muddy" is because if you simply linearly ramp up the red (`#ff0000`) at the same time as ramping down green (`#00ff00`) the middle colour ends up as `#808000` instead of `#ffff00`.

Instead, find the HSL (or HSV) equivalent of your starting colour, and the same for the end colour.  Interpolate in *that* colour space, and then for each point convert back to RGB again.

Since the `S` and `L` (or `V`) values are the same for fully saturated red and green, only the `H` (hue) variable will change, giving the proper effect of a *spectrum* of colour.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to update [Mark Renouf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7871291/1650674) to handle alpha channel as well:

```
private float interpolate(float a, float b, float proportion) {
    return (a + ((b - a) * proportion));
}

/**
 * Returns an interpolated color, between <code>a</code> and <code>b</code>
 * proportion = 0, results in color a
 * proportion = 1, results in color b
 */
private int interpolateColor(int a, int b, float proportion) {

    if (proportion > 1 || proportion < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("proportion must be [0 - 1]");
    }
    float[] hsva = new float[3];
    float[] hsvb = new float[3];
    float[] hsv_output = new float[3];

    Color.colorToHSV(a, hsva);
    Color.colorToHSV(b, hsvb);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        hsv_output[i] = interpolate(hsva[i], hsvb[i], proportion);
    }

    int alpha_a = Color.alpha(a);
    int alpha_b = Color.alpha(b);
    float alpha_output = interpolate(alpha_a, alpha_b, proportion);

    return Color.HSVToColor((int) alpha_output, hsv_output);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Some of solutions of this thread didn't work for me, so I create another solution. Maybe it is useful for someone.

```
/**
 * Get the color between two given colors
 * @param colorStart int color start of degradate
 * @param colorEnd int color end of degradate
 * @param percent int percent to apply (0 to 100)
 * @return int color of degradate for given percent
 */
public static int getColorOfDegradate(int colorStart, int colorEnd, int percent){
    return Color.rgb(
            getColorOfDegradateCalculation(Color.red(colorStart), Color.red(colorEnd), percent),
            getColorOfDegradateCalculation(Color.green(colorStart), Color.green(colorEnd), percent),
            getColorOfDegradateCalculation(Color.blue(colorStart), Color.blue(colorEnd), percent)
    );
}

private static int getColorOfDegradateCalculation(int colorStart, int colorEnd, int percent){
    return ((Math.min(colorStart, colorEnd)*(100-percent)) + (Math.max(colorStart, colorEnd)*percent)) / 100;
}
```

Comment: awesome! Works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

In Compose its simple you can use [lerp](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/util/package-summary#lerp(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float))

basically it's

> Linearly interpolate between start color and stop color with fraction fraction
> between them.

for eg.

```
lerp(
     Color.Red,
     Color.Black,
     fraction // @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways to interpolate:

```
private static float interpolate(final float a, final float b, final float proportion) {
    return a + (b - a) * proportion;
}

/** Returns an interpoloated color, between <code>a</code> and <code>b</code> */
public static int interpolateColorHsv(final int a, final int b, final float proportion) {
    final float[] hsva = new float[3];
    final float[] hsvb = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(a, hsva);
    Color.colorToHSV(b, hsvb);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        hsvb[i] = interpolate(hsva[i], hsvb[i], proportion);
    }
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsvb);
}

public static int interpolateRGB(final int colorA, final int colorB, final float bAmount) {
    final float aAmount = 1.0f - bAmount;
    final int red = (int) (Color.red(colorA) * aAmount + Color.red(colorB) * bAmount);
    final int green = (int) (Color.green(colorA) * aAmount + Color.green(colorB) * bAmount);
    final int blue = (int) (Color.blue(colorA) * aAmount + Color.blue(colorB) * bAmount);
    return Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
}
```