# how to make a color similar to another color by percentage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have two colors in hex form, `#000000` and `#ffffff`. I want to approximate the first color to the second color by a percentage. 
Something like:

```
var percent=0.50;
var color1='#000000';
var color2='#ffffff';

var newcolor=approximateColor1ToColor2ByPercent(color1,color2,percent);
//newcolor should be a gray like #808080
```

how to do this?

Comment: You mean, you want to mix the black into white?

Comment: Colour mixing is complicated. See these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205472/why-wont-my-color-mixing-function-work-as-expected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351442/is-there-an-algorithm-for-color-mixing-that-works-like-mixing-real-colors and the colour blending functions in the less.js library https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/functions/color-blending.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### For Additive Color mixing:

To mix the two colors, do this:

```
function approximateColor1ToColor2ByPercent(color1, color2, percent) {
  var red1 = parseInt(color1[1] + color1[2], 16);
  var green1 = parseInt(color1[3] + color1[4], 16);
  var blue1 = parseInt(color1[5] + color1[6], 16);

  var red2 = parseInt(color2[1] + color2[2], 16);
  var green2 = parseInt(color2[3] + color2[4], 16);
  var blue2 = parseInt(color2[5] + color2[6], 16);

  var red = Math.round(mix(red1, red2, percent));
  var green = Math.round(mix(green1, green2, percent));
  var blue = Math.round(mix(blue1, blue2, percent));

  return generateHex(red, green, blue);
}

function generateHex(r, g, b) {
  r = r.toString(16);
  g = g.toString(16);
  b = b.toString(16);

  // to address problem mentioned by Alexis Wilke:
  while (r.length < 2) { r = "0" + r; }
  while (g.length < 2) { g = "0" + g; }
  while (b.length < 2) { b = "0" + b; }

  return "#" + r + g + b;
}

function mix(start, end, percent) {
    return start + ((percent) * (end - start));
}
```

Then this following code:

```
approximateColor1ToColor2ByPercent('#000000', '#ffffff', .50);
```

will return `'#808080'`

Comment: This will blend yellow + blue to grey, which may or may not be what is wanted. There are many other possible algorithms for mixing colours.

Comment: @Stuart - I just realized that when mixing colors such as pure yellow and blue on the additive color model, it results in grey.  This is because you are basically mixing 50% red, 50% green, and 50% blue.  You may need to look at subtractive mixing, which I will put in my answer.

Comment: What happens if a resulting color is between 0 and 15 (0x0F)?

Comment: @AlexisWilke - yeah, that's another thing I'm going to fix.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**ES6** implementation:

Actually, I just re-write the right answer of this post in *ES6* and typed with TypeScript language:

```js
const generateHex = (r: number, g: number, b: number): string => {
  let R = r.toString(16);
  let G = g.toString(16);
  let B = b.toString(16);

  while (R.length < 2) {
    R = `0${R}`;
  }
  while (G.length < 2) {
    G = `0${G}`;
  }
  while (B.length < 2) {
    B = `0${B}`;
  }

  return `#${R}${G}${B}`;
};

const mix = (start: number, end: number, percent: number): number =>
    start + (percent / 100) * (end - start);

const blender = (color1: string, color2: string, percent: number): string => {
  const red1 = parseInt(`${color1[1]}${color1[2]}`, 16);
  const green1 = parseInt(`${color1[3]}${color1[4]}`, 16);
  const blue1 = parseInt(`${color1[5]}${color1[6]}`, 16);

  const red2 = parseInt(`${color2[1]}${color2[2]}`, 16);
  const green2 = parseInt(`${color2[3]}${color2[4]}`, 16);
  const blue2 = parseInt(`${color2[5]}${color2[6]}`, 16);

  const red = Math.round(mix(red1, red2, percent));
  const green = Math.round(mix(green1, green2, percent));
  const blue = Math.round(mix(blue1, blue2, percent));

  return generateHex(red, green, blue);
};

export default blender;
```

**ATTENTION**: The `blender` function merge two given colors with the **percentage number**, ***IT MEANS THE PERCEN NUMBER SHOULD BE BETWEEN 0 ~ 100***, for a test you can use below code:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = blender('#ffffff', '#ff0000', 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not professional, just share my efforts.

The way of performance colors between nature and computer is **different**.To get color similar to what you want, you may use light blue(`#00FFFF`) instead of (`#OOOOFF`).

So I've tried two ways of color blending, first is the traditional additive mixing:

```
newColor.R = (color1.R + color2.R)/2
```

For alpha blending, color1 and color2 both have their own alpha channel which represents the transparency of itself.So alpha blending algorithm should be like(R,G,B ranges from 0 to 255):

```
newAlpha = 1 - (1-color1.Alpha) * (1-color2.Alpha)
newColor.R = (color1.R/255 * color1.Alpha / newAlpha + color2.R/255 * color2.Alpha * (1-color1.Alpha) / newAlpha)*255
```

I've implemented them, and you can see the result:

```js
//Convert hex color into rgb color
function HexToRgb(hexcolor) {
  var hexR = hexcolor.substr(0, 2);
  var hexG = hexcolor.substr(2, 2);
  var hexB = hexcolor.substr(4, 2);
  var rgbColor = [];
  rgbColor[0] = parseInt(hexR, 16);
  rgbColor[1] = parseInt(hexG, 16);
  rgbColor[2] = parseInt(hexB, 16);
  return rgbColor;
}

//Convert rgb color int hex color
function RgbtoHex(rgbcolor) {
  var hexColor = rgbcolor[0].toString(16) + rgbcolor[1].toString(16) + rgbcolor[2].toString(16);
  return hexColor;
}

//Additive mixing two colors
function additiveMixing(color1, color2) {
  var rgbColor1 = HexToRgb(arguments[0]);
  var rgbColor2 = HexToRgb(arguments[1]);

  var newColor = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    newColor[n] = Math.round((rgbColor1[n] + rgbColor2[n]) / 2);
  }
  return RgbtoHex(newColor);
}

//Alpha blending two colors with two alphas
function alphaBlending(color1, color2, alpha1, alpha2) {
  var rgbColor1 = HexToRgb(arguments[0]);
  var rgbColor2 = HexToRgb(arguments[1]);

  var newColor = [];
  var alpha1 = arguments[2];
  var alpha2 = arguments[3];
  var alpha = 1 - (1 - alpha1) * (1 - alpha2);
  for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    newColor[n] = Math.round((rgbColor1[n] / 255.0 * alpha1 / alpha + rgbColor2[n] / 255.0 * alpha2 * (1 - alpha1) / alpha) * 255);
  }
  return RgbtoHex(newColor);
}

//Show base color change
$("#color1, #color2").change(function() {
  var color = $(this).val();
  $(this).next().css("background-color", color);
});

//Mix color
$("button").click(function() {
  var color1 = $("#color1").val().substr(1);
  var color2 = $("#color2").val().substr(1);
  var alpha1 = parseFloat($("#alpha1").val());
  var alpha2 = parseFloat($("#alpha2").val());
  var additiveColor = additiveMixing(color1, color2);
  var alphablendColor = alphaBlending(color1, color2, alpha1, alpha2);

  $("#additive span").text("#" + additiveColor);
  $("#additive span").parent().next().css("background-color", "#" + additiveColor);

  $("#alpha span").text("#" + alphablendColor);
  $("#alpha span").parent().next().css("background-color", "#" + alphablendColor);
});
```

```css
.color_block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#result {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="color1">Color 1</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="color1" type="text" value="#00FFFF" />
    <div class="color_block" style="background-color: #0000FF;"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="color2">Color 2</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="color2" type="text" value="#FFFF00" />
    <div class="color_block" style="background-color: #FFFF00;"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="alpha1">Alpha 1(0-1)</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="alpha1" type="text" value="0.5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="alpha2">Alpha 2(0-1)</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="alpha2" type="text" value="0.5" />
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<button>Mix them!</button>
<div id="result">
  <p id="additive">Additive mixed color is <span>N/A</span>
  </p>
  <div class="color_block"></div>
  <p id="alpha">Alpha blending mixed color is <span>N/A</span>
  </p>
  <div class="color_block"></div>
</div>
```

**Reference:**

- [Why won't my color mixing function work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205472/why-wont-my-color-mixing-function-work-as-expected)
- [Is there an algorithm for color mixing that works like mixing real colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351442/is-there-an-algorithm-for-color-mixing-that-works-like-mixing-real-colors)
- [Algorithm for Additive Color Mixing for RGB Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values)

Comment: Your rgbtohex function doesn't always work - try mixing #000ff with #ff0000 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb for solutions.