# javascript - Mix three colors by percentage

Tags: javascript

In my javascript application I have to mix three colors red, yellow and green. I have to mix them by percentage specified for each color something like:

`mixColours(redColor, yellowColor, greenColor, redPercentage, yellowPercentage, greenPercentage)`

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53792583) solution on SO, but this only works for two colors.

Is it possible to achieve the mix of three colors? If yes, can anybody share some piece of code, please?

Comment: can you give input-output examples for your requirement.. eg .. what values your function will take and what will be the corresponding output

Comment: You can try to add two colors in their respective proportions and then add a third color with the resultant again in their respective proportions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

- Extract colors
- round the final color

```
const mixColours = (color1, color2, color3, percentage1, percentage2, percentage3) => {
    const red1 = parseInt(color1.slice(1, 3), 16);
    const green1 = parseInt(color1.slice(3, 5), 16);
    const blue1 = parseInt(color1.slice(5, 7), 16);
  
    const red2 = parseInt(color2.slice(1, 3), 16);
    const green2 = parseInt(color2.slice(3, 5), 16);
    const blue2 = parseInt(color2.slice(5, 7), 16);
  
    const red3 = parseInt(color3.slice(1, 3), 16);
    const green3 = parseInt(color3.slice(3, 5), 16);
    const blue3 = parseInt(color3.slice(5, 7), 16);
  
    const red = Math.round((red1 * percentage1 + red2 * percentage2 + red3 * percentage3) / (percentage1 + percentage2 + percentage3));
    const green = Math.round((green1 * percentage1 + green2 * percentage2 + green3 * percentage3) / (percentage1 + percentage2 + percentage3));
    const blue = Math.round((blue1 * percentage1 + blue2 * percentage2 + blue3 * percentage3) / (percentage1 + percentage2 + percentage3));
  
    return generateHex(red, green, blue);
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If you click `[<>]` you can make a [mcve] with an example call