# Represent Percentage Value (0-100) in Color (from Red to Green)

Tags: android, colors

I have an Android app with a dynamically updating percentage (between 0 and 100). The app has two specific colors - light red (#BD4141) and light green (#719D98).

I would like an element to have the light red color background when the given percentage is 0 and light green when it's 100. Intermediary percentage should represent a soft transition color representation between these two colors.

Alternatively, I would like it to go from solid red to solid green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This code is not optimized but it does what it is meant to do.*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.screen_main);

        final SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar,
                    final int progress, final boolean fromUser) {
                update(seekBar);
            }
        });
        update(sb);
    }

    private void update(final SeekBar sb) {
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        final int colorStart = Color.parseColor("#BD4141");
        final int colorEnd = Color.parseColor("#719D98");

        layout.setBackgroundColor(interpolateColor(colorStart, colorEnd,
                sb.getProgress() / 100f)); // assuming SeekBar max is 100
    }

    private float interpolate(final float a, final float b,
            final float proportion) {
        return (a + ((b - a) * proportion));
    }

    private int interpolateColor(final int a, final int b,
            final float proportion) {
        final float[] hsva = new float[3];
        final float[] hsvb = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(a, hsva);
        Color.colorToHSV(b, hsvb);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            hsvb[i] = interpolate(hsva[i], hsvb[i], proportion);
        }
        return Color.HSVToColor(hsvb);
    }

}
```

This answer is based on question and answers from [android color between two colors, based on percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414673/android-color-between-two-colors-based-on-percentage).