# Android progress bar with color plate

Tags: android, background, progress-bar

Does any one knows any way to change background of a progress bar to sth like this image?[image]

As you can see there is a color plate in background which starts from green to red and there is an indicator which shows a title. I have no idea how to make it or if there is some keywords to search about it or even some liberaries.

thanks very much

P.S: It seems this is what I need.
https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar

Comment: try to set the progressDrawable in your xml..

Comment: @TabishHussain thanks very much but what about its indicator sign?

Comment: Check this link I hope it helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140429/represent-percentage-value-0-100-in-color-from-red-to-green](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140429/represent-percentage-value-0-100-in-color-from-red-to-green)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seekbar for the indicator with thumb image changes and background as progress drawable in your xml.
Search for customizing seekbar and see whatever suits the best for your requirement.