# How to gradually change colour of a view with seek bar?

Tags: android, layout, colors

I need to change the colour of a layout using the seek bar, from 0xC4DF9B to 0xA2CC61, say & am really struggling. Here is what I have so far:

XML:

```
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/tile1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:background="#C4DF9B">

       </LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
    @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            int seekValue = seekBar.getProgress();

            tile1.setBackgroundColor() // ???

        }
```

Comment: Can you adapt [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7871291/2911458) to suit your needs? You may need to convert from `progress` to `proportion`.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure... Thanks for the link though