# How to change the background color of an ImageView using for example a SeekBar?

Tags: android, colors, imageview, seekbar

I would like to do the following:

1. I have a `LinearLayout` with several `ImageViews` with background colors defined in their xml.
2. I have a `SeekBar`.
3. By moving the `Seekbar` I should change the colors of the `Imageviews` background.

I would like to save the default background colors but can`t find getbackgroundcolor method, only setbackground method.

Later I would like to change the colors as the `Seekbar` is progressing.

I have something like this now:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int test = seekBar.getProgress();
    //textView.setText("Valami" + test);
    switch (test) {
    case 0:             
        imageView0.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        imageView1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        break;
    case 1:
        imageView0.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  
        break;
    case 2:
        imageView0.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
       break;
}
```

I think this is not the right way, and I would like to change their color by getting the actual `SeekBar` progress value. For example add some value to the original color code based on the progress value.

This is my idea, but I don`t know how to implement it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See my comment here for a related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564080/how-to-gradually-change-colour-of-a-view-with-seek-bar?noredirect=1#comment41750191_26564080

Comment: Hi stkent,

Thanks I will check the related solution you mentioned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from stkent has helped me.

Actually the answer in this post: [android color between two colors, based on percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414673/android-color-between-two-colors-based-on-percentage/7871291#7871291) has helped me a lot.

In this case Mark Renouf`s solution was very helpful.

Thanks!