# change the background Brightness

Tags: android

I want to know if it was possible to change the Brightness of an app to do a good effect on my splash screen thanks for helping. I just want to do an effect dark and progressively put more and more light and after it change screen like normal splash screen.

Thanks for helping 
public class firstscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView( activity_firstscreen );
    final int MAGENTA;

    Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int x=1;
            int total=1;
            float percentage = x/total;
            int color;

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );
            finish();
        }

    };

    new Handler( ).postDelayed( runnable, 3000 );

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Darken or Lighten the background color of your screen. This gives the impression of dimming or lightning the brightness.

Using something like:

- [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)
  or
- [android color between two colors, based on percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414673/android-color-between-two-colors-based-on-percentage)

You would then create a Timer/Loop ([like CountdownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)) and every Tick get the color off the background and update it.

---

There are many ways to do it, here's a quick one I looked up.

Try this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/graphics/ColorUtils.html#blendARGB(int,%20int,%20float)

```
val white: Int = Color.WHITE // White
val yourColor = Color.RED // Whatever your color is
val newColor = ColorUtils.blendARGB(yourColor, white, 0.5)
```

This will blend your color 50% towards white aka bright.

Comment: they don't explain how to apply the changes of colour in the java code

Comment: Thought the second one did, plus this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color

Comment: can you please give me the line of code the website is hard to reach on my laptop

Comment: You haven't put any code on your question, so its a bit abstract to give you a coding answer. You need to read the documentation on the links.